# Multi web sites based on country/region

Tags: c#, azure, iis

I want to create a web site which will have traffic from different parts of the world. So in order to improve the performance I am planing to host the web site on multiple Geo locations(Azure servers). 
So my web site URL will be something like this,

```
domain/country_code
```

Based on the country_code, I have to redirect user to correct server. My problem is I cannot point same domain to multiple servers. Anyone know how this is implemented on other web sites such as Samsung, Apple etc.

Comment: i believe what you can do is to host your web app in multiple servers with the azure domain (xxx.azurewebsites) and then you setup an azure traffic manager to redirect all requests from your domain to the right instance based on the location. For more information about traffic manager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-nested-profiles

Answer (score 1):

Assuming , this is something which you are looking for:

[image]

In this scenario ,there are some services that allow for an application to achieve a much higher level of global availability. These services are truly global services within Azure and both offer a different kind of service that when used together offer amazing application availability scenarios to be built at a global scale. These services are:

- Azure Traffic Manager
- Azure CDN

Azure Traffic Manager is a DNS-based traffic load balancer that enables you to distribute traffic optimally to services across global Azure regions, while providing high availability and responsiveness.

Traffic Manager uses DNS to direct client requests to the most appropriate service endpoint based on a traffic-routing method and the health of the endpoints. An endpoint is any Internet-facing service hosted inside or outside of Azure.

Check this link for additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview

https://buildazure.com/designing-globally-resilient-apps-with-azure-app-service-and-cosmos-db/

Hope it helps, Let me know if you need any more details.